# JQGrid Pivot - Aggregate with string values

Tags: jqgrid

Is it possible to convert integer/numeric data to string values in aggregate:? I just need to convert the data in a pivot format and display the aggregate data in string format. Right now I'm getting NaN for string values in aggregator columns. Is there any option to do this or any workaround.

Comment: _in aggregate without any sum, max aggregators etc?_

Comment: Yes, I need to get string values instead of integer/numeric format in aggregator values

Answer (score 0):

In case of using Guriddo jqGrid [aggregator can be a custom function](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/pivotgrid/#aggregates).
In the same documentation page you can see example of using custom aggregates.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, is it possible to covert Formatter: to string

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean. You may want to visit the [docs of the pivot here](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/pivotgrid/)